# Multirole iOS application - Should Logic in Same or Different View Controllers for Multiple Roles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm a newbie to iOS and now trying to design an app for multiple roles who can log in from home page.

At first, I tried to give each role a completely separate line of its own view controllers. But later, I found a lot of interfaces and codes are the same among different roles and it will be a huge amount of work to copy and paste.

So now, I try to have only one major line of view controllers and then capture the user identity to change the display (hide and unhide functions) according to different roles. But I'm not sure if this is the real preferred way to handle this kind of multirole application?

(If my question is not clear, please tell me!)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "role"?

Comment: @RyanTobin For example, I have "Brand Ambassador", "Brand Administrator" and "Store Administrator" who can all log in to see their own interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **have only one major line of view controllers and then capture the user identity to change the display (hide and unhide functions) according to different roles.**

This is the most efficient way to do this, because that way you don't repeat yourself. Having too much code (view controllers) for just small changes will create unnecessary clutter, both code-wise and space-wise.

Even if you are a newbie, try to implement best practices wherever you can, because people generally get used to what they did when they were new, and changing how you write code when you are more experienced is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

> First you are new to iOS.Now you are going to develop application with
>   multiple roles  like Register,Login,Showing List,Edit
>   Page,Settings.....etc.If you are a newbie you can create separate view
>   controller for above thing.If you want to use string,id,number,...or
>   anything globally you can create singleton class for access that.If
>   you gain experience or If you get more knowledge,you can create common
>   view controller and class for accessing functions,variables in whole
>   project.Now you must learn basic things for creating application and
>   use without any error,crash.Learn all basics first.

Comment: Actually, for multiple roles I mean people's identities like "brand ambassador", "brand administrator" and "store administrator" ... etc. I'm not completely new but have been learning objective-c for several months. So I'm really curious about the real way to do it.